# Write a While loop in Impala SQL?

Tags: hadoop, impala

What is the syntax for writing a while loop in Impala? Is it even possible to write a loop? I cant seem to declare variables and it doesn't recognize "while" as a keyword.

Comment: None of the Hadoop sql dialects support procedural loops... What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impala doesn't support `WHILE` loops in it's syntax.

References:

[Impala Reserved Words](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_reserved_words.html)

Comment: Thanks, Do you know if it supports any loop syntax?

Comment: Not really.  If you want to do something like that you might look at `impyla` from https://github.com/cloudera/impyla.  This will allow you to write looping constructs over Impala.