# For loops in impala

Tags: hadoop, impala

I saw the question 
[Write a While loop in Impala SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523380/write-a-while-loop-in-impala-sql), but this doesn't address the "for" keyword.

Is "for" not used for looping? And if not, what is it used for? Something similar to "UNIQUE FOR"?

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a different sort of language, it doesn't have that sort of looping/iterative capability.

Treating data as blocks and your query acting over every record at the same time is a good approach conceptually.

If you haven't used it before it worthwhile knowing a bit about set logic

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand set logic and SQL; I do not mean to loop like a CURSOR. I'm referring to partitioning a set by an iterated value, like a normalized invoice date column and looping month over month in batches. From a code maintainability/readability perspective, iterative approaches can be valuable instead of using lag/lead approaches, especially when lag/lead is a value you're joining on. Do you have an explanation of the Impala "for" keyword, by any chance? It looks like "while" is being introduced in the near future.

Comment: Also, T-SQL has WHILE capabilities. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Group by would be the obvious answer with a case statement. For each of the normalised columns.  My point was you can use a view or a plain select to create batches but record level processing in my view isn't a good choice in sql.  If you are processing in batches, use the wrapper script you are using for execution to do batch control.

Comment: Remember that impala and hive aren't full sql, they are sql like