# Iterative functions for Apache Impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, sql-like, cloudera, impala

am working on my graduation project and its using Impala , 
so i want to ask is there anyway so i can use options like ' for , if , while ' ... etc in Cloudera Impala ?

Comment: Those are not functions (in general)

Comment: thanks for the information maybe i posted the question in wrong way .. but can u answer my question ?

Answer (score 0):

@Atef Ibrahim you can use if :

```
if(boolean condition, type ifTrue, type ifFalseOrNull)
```

for more info you can read the doc [Impala Conditional Functions](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_conditional_functions.html#conditional_functions)

Regarding the for/while loop statement  you can read 
[Write a While loop in Impala SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523380/write-a-while-loop-in-impala-sql?rq=1)